# Grip shift won't move

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano

Just bought a used shockwave sus:550 bike with grip shift shimano gears.
The grip shift won't move no matter how much force is applied. Also the chain skips as one rides despite a recent lube job. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Depends - how mechanically minded are you?  Are you good with tools?

Comment: Looks like a BSO, so you likely have the cheapest grip shifts possible and they might just be better off just replaced.

Comment: They can be quite stiff even when working properly (especially the front) so it probably doesn't take much to completely seize them

Comment: @Criggie newbie eager to learn

Comment: @starred well you're in the right place.  Consider extending your question with further information, or try the [chat] room called the Velodrome.

Answer (score 5):

You want to try moving the derailleur by pushing it with you hand, which will isolate whether the mechanism is stuck, or if the grip part is stuck.  If you have exposed inner wires, then try pulling them with your hand to see if the derailleur mech moves.

Could be corroded wires in outer sheaths, damaged grip control, or corroded/frozen derailleur.

Note that twist shifts/grip shifts were pretty low on the quality scale, and tended to indicate a budget bike.  You might be on a hiding to nothing spending money on this bike.

---

Chain skip sounds like worn sprockets on the rear wheel, an elongated chain, and possibly impacted dirt between the sprockets stopping the chain sitting on the teeth properly.

Consider posting clear and well lit closeup photos of the parts, which may help others answer more accurately.

Comment: The skip could also be from the derailleur position given that the shifting is wonky.